# Wp_Query Post per page not working?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have specified the post per page to be 3 as arg but it does not seems to work, all the post are being shown up. Not sure why i works if i enable no paging false but pagination shows up.

```
Array
    (
        [post_type] => post
        [post_status] => publish
        [paged] => 1
        [nopaging] => true
        [posts_per_page] => 3
        [order] => ASC
        [orderby] => none
    )
```

Comment: Remove [`nopaging`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) from query parameters.

Comment: @nmr yah that seems to be the solution..but for me if i remove no paging, pagination shows up

Comment: @nmr i actually wanted just show 3 posts without pagination

Comment: `WP_Query` "only" performs a query to the database. A different function is responsible for displaying paging, although it is based on the number of results that match the query. You can remove code responsible for pagination ( probably the function `paginate_links()`) from template.

Comment: @nmr thank you I have added unset() based on condition to get over this. Please make it as an answer.

Comment: Enabling `nopaging` means you're retrieving all results (no `LIMIT` clause) - equivalent to setting `posts_per_page` to `-1`. If you want to limit the number of posts and also disable pagination, then omit the `nopaging` parameter and try setting `no_found_rows` to `true`. After all - when pagination is not needed, enabling `no_found_rows` can improve performance.

Comment: You can write how you solved it in your code. What I wrote is not a complete answer, rather a small suggestion. You will probably have to wait 2 days to accept the answer.